# My data extraction is off with line analysis in python. I need some guidance on where I'm going wrong

Tags: python-3.x, extract, data-analysis

[Student Bill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb5rk.png) [Student Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZejV.png) So! I'm working on data extraction for my company (a university) and while it works as advertised extracting data, its not getting the right data. I've run a different script for line analysis to determine where I should be looking, but after that and finding what I want to extract... my code just doesn't seem to want to extract said lines properly.

I'm at a standstill -- this is by no means necessary. I don't have to do this for a work project, etc. I'm really just trying to save myself time renaming 1000's of files manually. But I can't do that until I get this first part done. So thanks in advance for any tips or help you can provide!

```
import os
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from docx import Document
import PyPDF2

def extract_text_from_pdf(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        text = ' '.join(page.extract_text() or '' for page in reader.pages)
    return text

def extract_info_from_pdf(pdf_path, doc_type):
    extracted_data = {}
    with fitz.open(pdf_path) as doc:
        text = ""
        for page in doc:
            text += page.get_text("text")
    lines = text.split('\n')
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        print(f"Analyzing line {i}: {line}")  # Verbose logging for each line
        if doc_type == 'bill':
            if 'Student ID:' in line:
                extracted_data['Student ID'] = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
                print(f"Extracted Student ID: {extracted_data['Student ID']} from line {i}")
            elif 'Bill Term:' in line and i + 1 < len(lines):
                bill_term_parts = lines[i + 1].strip().split()
                if len(bill_term_parts) >= 2:
                    extracted_data['Semester'] = bill_term_parts[0]
                    extracted_data['Year'] = bill_term_parts[1]
                    print(f"Extracted Semester and Year: {extracted_data['Semester']} {extracted_data['Year']} from lines {i}, {i+1}")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to extract full Bill Term from line {i+1}")
        elif doc_type == 'invoice':
            if 'Student ID' in line:
                extracted_data['Student ID'] = line.split()[-1]
                print(f"Extracted Student ID: {extracted_data['Student ID']} from line {i}")
            elif 'Last Name' in line:
                extracted_data['Last Name'] = line.split()[-1]
                print(f"Extracted Last Name: {extracted_data['Last Name']} from line {i}")
            elif 'REFERENCE:' in line:
                extracted_data['Reference ID'] = line.split()[-1]
                print(f"Extracted Reference ID: {extracted_data['Reference ID']} from line {i}")

    if not extracted_data:
        print(f"No data was extracted from {doc_type} at {pdf_path}. Check document formatting and content.")
    return extracted_data



def create_output_doc(extracted_data, analysis_info, doc_type, output_dir):
    doc = Document()
    doc.add_heading(f'Data Extraction Report - {doc_type}', 0)
    for key, value in extracted_data.items():
        doc.add_paragraph(f'{key}: {value}')
    # Include detailed analysis information
    doc.add_heading('Detailed Analysis', level=1)
    for i, detail in enumerate(analysis_info):
        doc.add_paragraph(f'Line {i}: {detail}')
    if not extracted_data:
        doc.add_paragraph("No data was extracted. Possible reasons include incorrect document format or missing expected information.")
    output_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'detailed_output_{doc_type}.docx')
    doc.save(output_filename)
    print(f"Detailed report generated: {output_filename}")


# Main extraction and document creation
pdf_dir = r"C:\Users\jrm4\Box\Test Folder\Test Bill"  # Update this path based on your directory
for filename in os.listdir(pdf_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        file_path = os.path.join(pdf_dir, filename)
        doc_type = 'bill' if 'bill' in filename.lower() else 'invoice'
        extracted_info = extract_info_from_pdf(file_path, doc_type)
        create_output_doc(extracted_info, doc_type, pdf_dir)
```

So this is my data line breakdown, and it worked great. Gave me what I assumed was the proper breakdown of lines on pdf files. Afterwards, I applied the lines I needed to the respective next code snippet and that's where life gets hairy.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
import PyPDF2
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def extract_text_from_pdf(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        text = ' '.join(page.extract_text() or '' for page in reader.pages)
    return text


def extract_data_from_pdf(lines, doc_type):
    extracted_data = {}
    print(f"Starting data extraction for {doc_type} document")
    if doc_type == 'bill':
        # Extract 'Student ID'
        extracted_data['Student ID'] = lines[1].strip() if len(lines) > 1 else 'Unknown'
        # Extract and split 'Semester' and 'Year'
        if len(lines) > 7:
            parts = lines[7].split()  # Use space to split 'Semester' and 'Year'
            if len(parts) >= 2:
                extracted_data['Semester'], extracted_data['Year'] = parts[0], parts[1]
                print(f"Extracted Semester and Year: {parts[0]} {parts[1]}")
            else:
                print(f"Error: Expected 'Semester Year' format, got: '{lines[7]}'")

        else:
            print("Error: Bill document is shorter than expected.")
    elif doc_type == 'invoice':
        # Similar logic for invoice, ensuring to log each step
        extracted_data['Student ID'] = lines[0].strip() if len(lines) > 0 else 'Missing'
        extracted_data['Last Name'] = lines[26].strip() if len(lines) > 26 else 'Missing'
        extracted_data['Reference ID'] = lines[57].strip() if len(lines) > 57 else 'Missing'
        # Verbose logging for extracted data
        print(f"Extracted from invoice: Student ID - {extracted_data['Student ID']}, Last Name - {extracted_data['Last Name']}, Reference ID - {extracted_data['Reference ID']}")
    return extracted_data



def update_excel(workbook_path, combined_data):
    workbook = load_workbook(workbook_path)
    sheet = workbook.active
    print("Updating Excel sheet with combined data:")
    for index, (student_id, info) in enumerate(combined_data.items(), start=2):
        # Log what's being written to Excel
        print(f"Row {index}: Student ID - {student_id}, Reference ID - {info.get('Reference ID')}, Last Name - {info.get('Last Name')}, Semester - {info.get('Semester')}, Year - {info.get('Year')}")
        sheet[f'A{index}'] = student_id
        sheet[f'B{index}'] = info.get('Reference ID', 'Unknown')
        sheet[f'C{index}'] = info.get('Last Name', 'Unknown')
        sheet[f'D{index}'] = info.get('Semester', 'Unknown')
        sheet[f'E{index}'] = info.get('Year', 'Unknown')
        formatted_data = f"{info.get('Reference ID', 'Unknown')}_{info.get('Last Name', 'Unknown')}_{info.get('Semester', 'Unknown')} {info.get('Year', 'Unknown')}_INVOICE/STATEMENT"
        sheet[f'F{index}'] = formatted_data
    workbook.save(workbook_path)
    print("Excel sheet updated.")



# Paths to your documents
invoice_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\jrm4\Box\Test Folder\Test Invoice")
bill_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\jrm4\Box\Test Folder\Test Bill")
excel_path = Path(r"C:\Users\jrm4\Box\Test Folder\Test Book.xlsx")

# Process and combine data
def process_pdfs(directory, doc_type):
    results = {}
    for pdf_path in directory.glob('*.pdf'):
        text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)
        result = extract_data_from_pdf(text, doc_type)
        if result and 'Student ID' in result:
            results[result['Student ID']] = result
        else:
            print(f"Data extraction failed for: {pdf_path.name}")
    return results

invoice_data = process_pdfs(invoice_dir, 'invoice')
bill_data = process_pdfs(bill_dir, 'bill')
combined_data = {}  # Combine based on 'Student ID'
for student_id in set(invoice_data) | set(bill_data):
    combined_data[student_id] = {**invoice_data.get(student_id, {}), **bill_data.get(student_id, {})}

# Update Excel
update_excel(excel_path, combined_data)
```

I'll post my output from the console to show you what I mean:

Starting data extraction for invoice document
**Extracted from invoice: Student ID - E, Last Name - , Reference ID - 0**
Starting data extraction for bill document
**Error: Expected 'Semester Year' format, got: ' '**
Updating Excel sheet with combined data:
**Row 2: Student ID - E, Reference ID - 0, Last Name - , Semester - None, Year - None**
**Row 3: Student ID - t, Reference ID - None, Last Name - None, Semester - None, Year - None**
Excel sheet updated.

So that's where I'm at. I've been at this since Monday and I'm at wits end. All pdf's for the sake of this example are the same. The invoices all look alike with the same placement across the board, while the bill is also the same. Once again, thanks for any and all help/recommendations in advance.

Comment: can we have a sample of what your data looks like, and what is the desired output?

Comment: I can't provide the data as its student data, and there are FERPA violations that would happen... but I can provide you what an expected outcome for those lines should be, 

Semester Year should be as it says (Spring 2024 for this example) which is then split to go into different excel columns. Student ID is kind of like a key between PDF's, as it should match and is an 8 Digit number with a U in front (U12345678) -- Reference ID is a number generated by specific embassies and changes are dependent on them. Usually looks like (12-35678 = )

Comment: Follow up to above comment -- rest should be pretty clear with the last name being the last name. I decided to only pull this from the invoicing sheet as its clear cut and doesn't need to be split like on the billing sheet. 

If you really need a sample, I can take a snip and add it, but a lot of the info will be redacted.

Comment: the best practice is too provide  minimal reproducing example. if you can't share your document you are more likely to receive aid if you can make a mock one

Comment: Also, quick follow up -- I won't be able to upload that snip until tomorrow morning if necessary as I'm now of work. :) But I still am interested in the help and replies! Will be checking through the evening.

Comment: @RomainL. added the images, but since I'm a new member, it changed them to links. Hope that helps!